# Xamarin Android Binding incorrect method override name

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Quite a strange problem in Xamarin.Android bindings. I have a java class defined as follows:

```java
// Java world
public abstract class BaseRenderableSeries<TX extends Comparable<TX>, 
          TY extends Comparable<TY>, 
          TRenderPassData extends ISeriesRenderPassData, 
          TDataSeries extends IDataSeries<TX, TY>> 

          implements IRenderableSeries {

    // ... 
    protected abstract IHitProvider<? super TRenderPassData> getHitProvider();
    // ... 
}
```

Derived classes in Java override `getHitProvider` as follows:

```java
public class FastLineRenderableSeries<TX extends Comparable<TX>, TY extends Comparable<TY>> extends XyRenderableSeriesBase<TX, TY, LineRenderPassData> {

    @Override
    protected IHitProvider<? super LineRenderPassData> getHitProvider() {
        return new CompositeHitProvider<>(
             new PointMarkerHitProvider(), 
             new LineHitProvider());
    }
}
```

In Xamarin.Android the binding is generated like this:

```cs
// Generated C# Binding in BaseRenderableSeries.cs
// 
protected abstract global::Com.Scichart.Charting.Visuals.RenderableSeries.HitTest.IHitProvider RawHitProvider {
    // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.scichart.charting.visuals.renderableSeries']/class[@name='BaseRenderableSeries']/method[@name='getHitProvider' and count(parameter)=0]"
    [Register ("getHitProvider", "()Lcom/scichart/charting/visuals/renderableSeries/hitTest/IHitProvider;", "GetGetHitProviderHandler")] get;
}
```

*Que?* The property has been renamed from **`HitProvider`** to **`RawHitProvider`**. Derived classes of `BaseRenderableSeries` are trying to override **`HitProvider`** though and this is causing a build error.

```cs
// Generated bindings in FastLineRenderableSeries.cs
protected override unsafe global::Com.Scichart.Charting.Visuals.RenderableSeries.HitTest.IHitProvider HitProvider {
    // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.scichart.charting.visuals.renderableSeries']/class[@name='FastLineRenderableSeries']/method[@name='getHitProvider' and count(parameter)=0]"
    [Register ("getHitProvider", "()Lcom/scichart/charting/visuals/renderableSeries/hitTest/IHitProvider;", "GetGetHitProviderHandler")]
    get {
           // ... 
        }
    }
}
```

> `FastLineRenderableSeries.HitProvider`: no suitable method to override

Any idea why? What's Xamarin doing here and how can I prevent its craziness?

Comment: You should be able to bring the correct name back with [`<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.scichart.charting.visuals.renderableSeries']/class[@name='BaseRenderableSeries']/method[@name='getHitProvider' and count(parameter)=0]" name="managedName">HitProvider</attr>` in EnumMethods.xml](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/customizing-bindings/java-bindings-metadata/), but I'm also curious why it happens in the first place.

Comment: Yes, the rubber ducking exercise above gave me that thought precisely. However it causes another problem. The BaseRenderableSeries property is named HitProvider (correct) but is now an abstract method (incorrect). The derived FastLineRenderableSeries property is also a method and marked as virtual, not override.

Answer (score 2):

That's because generics aren't supported. Maybe there is a possible name conflict wich the generator tries to avoid.

Option a)

Try to change the name of the Property in the base class

```xml
 <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.scichart.charting.visuals.renderableSeries']/class‌​[@name='BaseRenderableSeries']/method[@name='getHitProvider' and count(parameter)=0]" 
       name="managedName">HitProvider</attr>
```

Option b)

Change the name of the Property in the child classes

```xml
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.scichart.charting.visuals.renderableSeries']/class[@name='FastLineRenderableSeries']/method[@name='getHitProvider' and count(parameter)=0]" 
      name="managedName">RawHitProvider</attr>
```

Comment: Why would generics not supported cause a property to be renamed in one class but not another? I'm aware of Java generics / compilation / Xamarin problem - that's something else I need to work through

Comment: I had these kinds of problems only when generics come into play.

Comment: OK .. so a bug basically ^_^ I'll try suggestion 2, number 1 resulted in more wierdness

Comment: Noooooo. No bug. I had two one on one sessions about android bindings on the Xamarin Evolve last week. If one thing is true, then that there are NO bugs in the binding generator ;)

Comment: #ItsAFeature D: ... I shan't tell you about the other not bug where Errors disappear in Visual Studio and I have to do a force rebuild three times just to know what's broken...

Comment: Sadly, neither of these suggestions work. When Xamarin get's really confused then the *Invoker class (which you *cannot* modify via partial) also has a build error. Then you're stuffed. Solution might be to remove this property altogether and add it back later manually if we need it...

Comment: I think there is always a solution. But without further investigation (complete code) it's hard to figure out whats going on. What are the problems on both options?

Comment: I commented a bit above. With option 1, they become methods and the derived is virtual, not override, so conflicts. With option 2, the 'FastLineRenderableSeriesInvoker' doesn't implement HitProvider. Basically, it's bork3d

Comment: And if you rename it in the inferface `HitProvider` as well?

Comment: I've simply removed it for now with a `<remove-node/>` attribute. This way I can proceed with getting the whole thing to compile and later I may come back to this ...